# The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting error in my MVC application. I have page where some textfields and one dropdown is there. Data is loading correctly to that page when When I submit the page, `ModelState` is returning error that

> The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.

Controller methods

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{
    ....
    EditUserViewModel vm = new EditUserViewModel()
    .... // populate the view model including its SelectList properties
    return View(vm);
}
```

The data is correctly populated as per the following image

[image]

But when Its submitted back to controller, model state is invalid and gives error.

And view model

```
public class EditUserViewModel
{
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public string SelectedRoleName { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }
        public string SelectedCompanyID { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Companies { get; set; }
        ....
    }
```

View is as below

```
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserID)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedRoleName, Model.Roles)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCompanyID, Model.Companies, 
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Companies)
    ....

    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Comment: Which property is that error associated with (the errors suggests you have something in your view trying to bind to either `Roles` or `Companies` - do you have any inputs associated with them?)

Comment: When data is submitted back to controller Roles property is null. But when page is loaded everything is good on page. Its just when I submit back to controller then I see Roles is null

Comment: Roles would not be `null` unless you have created an input in your form associated with that property. You need to edit your question to show that (I assumed you have tried something like `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Roles)` which would cause that

Comment: No I haven't used any hidden.. You can check 1st screen shot there you can see in model there is Roles property with data. And html is also there Model.Roles but when same is submitted back to controller , its null

Comment: You have not shown the relevant information. The first screenshot tells us nothing - and the view would throw an exception if `Roles` was null :). What are you expecting? Your not (and should not) be generating a form control for each property of each `SelectListItem` in the `Roles` property so that property is never populated by the `DefaultModelBinder`. But that does not explain the `ModelState` error message your claiming which suggests you do have a hidden input something like I suggested in my previous comment

Comment: I have updated question with code when Page is opened.. its goes Edit(string id) method and loads data followed by screen shot of data.  Then I have html for Roles

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139007/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-mahajan344).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error occurs because of the following line of code in the view

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Companies)
```

If you inspect the html it is generating, it will be

```
<input ... name="Companies" value="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]" />`
```

When you submit the form, The `DefaultModelBinder` attempts to bind property `Companies` to that value and fails (you cannot bind a property which is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to a `string`).

Remove that line of code. And if you need to return the view because `ModelState` is invalid for other reasons, then re-populate the SelectLists before you return the view.

Comment: This is a similar issue I had. Ajax was trying to pass a list of types as a string query parameter. Thanks @Stephen for the hint

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this error by removing {get; set;} from the SelectListItem property

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Companies { get; set; }
```

replaced with

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Companies
```

Comment: Where is this defined?

Answer (score 0):

change input name .

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#Companies').attr('name', ' ');
};
```

Comment: While the code may meet the immediate need, answers with context are greatly desired.